# Configure 3 monitors positions with xrandr

Tags: xrandr

I m currently trying to configure my 3 monitors on my i3wm set-up but for some reasons, it doesn't work.

Here's my config:

- **OS:** Fedora Linux 35 (Thirty Five) x86_64
- **Kernel:** 5.16.18-200.fc35.x86_64
- **GPU:** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER
- **NVIDIA Driver Version:** 510.60.02

Here's the command I'm using :

```
xrandr --output DP-3 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate left --output DP-1 --pos 1080x840 --mode 1920x1080 --rotate normal --output HDMI-1 --pos 3000x840 --mode 1920x1080 --rotate normal
```

Here's what xrandr command result

```
    $ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 165.00   143.99   119.98    59.97    59.96    50.00    59.94    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     74.76    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    60.00    50.00    59.94    59.74  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   1440x480      60.00    59.94  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   720x576       50.00  
   700x525       74.76    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    75.00    72.81    75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04    70.08  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432       75.00  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 543mm x 302mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 143.99   119.98    59.97   109.95    99.93    59.96    50.00    59.94    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     74.76    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    60.00    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    60.00    50.00    59.94    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   720x576       50.00  
   700x525       74.76    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04    70.08  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432       75.00  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.96    59.93  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1600x1200     65.00    60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    70.07    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       70.00    65.00    60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       70.08  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       70.07    60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

And here's the actual positions of my monitors:

[image: Monitors]

EDIT: Adding more details about what is not working and what I ve already tried.

When I m logging in, here s the configuration I get :
[image: default display]

Then I run this command

```
xrandr --output DP-3 --rotate left
```

and I get this (which is almost perfect) :
[image: almostPerfect]

So the last thing to do is to put DP-3 at the right of DP-1. And this is where everything get messed up.

Either it works, the disposition is good, I can move the cursor from the left(DP-3) to the right (HDMI-1) going through the middle (DP-1) **but** when I opening a window on DP-1 it shows up on HDMI-1...

Either it doesn't work and all windows are in the wrong place, starting in the middle of the screen, with black space... chaotic. I will add a picture tonight..

Answer (score 0):

I just had to install the Nvidia drivers... Working perfectly now.

Here's my config:

- **OS:** Fedora Linux 35 (Thirty Five) x86_64
- **Kernel:** 5.16.18-200.fc35.x86_64
- **GPU:** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER
- **NVIDIA Driver Version:** 510.60.02

Useful links:

- to get the right driver: https://www.nvidia.fr/Download/index.aspx?lang=en
- fench tutorial that I used : https://doc.fedora-fr.org/wiki/Carte_graphique_NVIDIA_:_installation_des_pilotes_propri%C3%A9taires
- english equivalent : https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fedora-nvidia-drivers
- Bonus, how to fix tearing issues : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ux9bz_Tfw0